# Loop over list of dictionaries or flow mapping using Ansible?

Tags: data-structures, ansible, yaml

I have the following data structure.  I'm struggling to know precisely how to describe this data structure.  My first instinct is to call it a "list of dictionaries" but I've also been told it's called a "flow mapping".

```
site_subnets:
    - control: { network: "100.99.97.0/24", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
    - storage: { network: "100.99.98.0/24", mtu: "9000", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
    - data: { network: "100.99.99.0/24", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
    - site: { network: "100.99.0.0/16", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
    - local: { network: "100.99.44.1/22", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
```

For this particular exercise, I'd like to loop over the data structure and simply print the name of the item.

Here's the playbook I've written:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    site_subnets:
      - control: { network: "100.99.97.0/24", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
      - storage: { network: "100.99.98.0/24", mtu: "9000", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
      - data: { network: "100.99.99.0/24", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
      - site: { network: "100.99.0.0/16", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
      - local: { network: "100.99.44.1/22", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
  tasks:
    - name: site_subnet network names.
      debug:
        msg: "subnet name is: {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ site_subnets }}"
```

What I'm hoping to see is something like the following:

```
subnet name is: control
subnet name is: storage
subnet name is: data
subnet name is: site
subnet name is: local
```

Instead I'm seeing the entire dictionary returned upon evaluating each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is most certainly a `list` of `dict`s, and the [flow mapping](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#742-flow-mappings) is what the yaml spec calls the style of syntax that you used to define the interior `{ key: value }` pairs. If you were to say `- { control: { network: "...` then *all* of your dict structures would be in "flow mapping" style

Anyway, since you only care about the keys of those embedded dicts, [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-data-types) will allow you to "pivot" those dicts into `{key: control, value: {network: ...}}` shape, allowing `map(attribute="key")` to pull out just the keys. That `first` in in there because your top-level dict only has one key-value pair

```yaml
  - vars:
      site_subnets:
      - control: { network: "100.99.97.0/24", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
      - storage: { network: "100.99.98.0/24", mtu: "9000", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
      - data: { network: "100.99.99.0/24", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
      - site: { network: "100.99.0.0/16", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
      - local: { network: "100.99.44.1/22", mtu: "1500", dhcp_from_ip: "30", dhcp_to_ip: "50" }
    debug:
        msg: "subnet name is: {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ site_subnets | map('dict2items') | map('first') | map(attribute='key') }}"
```

yielding

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=control) => {
    "msg": "subnet name is: control"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=storage) => {
    "msg": "subnet name is: storage"
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. For example,

1. The simplest option is to get the key of a dictionary in a *loop*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "subnet name is: {{ item.keys()|first }}"
      loop: "{{ site_subnets }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'subnet name is: control'
  msg: 'subnet name is: storage'
  msg: 'subnet name is: data'
  msg: 'subnet name is: site'
  msg: 'subnet name is: local'
```

or, in a Jinja block

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for item in site_subnets %}
          subnet name is: {{ item.keys()|first }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives (abridged) in a single string

```yaml
  msg: |-
    subnet name is: control
    subnet name is: storage
    subnet name is: data
    subnet name is: site
    subnet name is: local
```

---

2. The next option is the conversion of the dictionaries. Create attributes *key* and *value*

```yaml
  site_subnets_attr: "{{ site_subnets|map('dict2items')|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  site_subnets_attr:
  - key: control
    value:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '1500'
      network: 100.99.97.0/24
  - key: storage
    value:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '9000'
      network: 100.99.98.0/24
  - key: data
    value:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '1500'
      network: 100.99.99.0/24
  - key: site
    value:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '1500'
      network: 100.99.0.0/16
  - key: local
    value:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '1500'
      network: 100.99.44.1/22
```

Then, the iteration is trivial

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "subnet name is: {{ item.key }}"
      loop: "{{ site_subnets_attr }}"
```

gives (abridged) the same result

```yaml
  msg: 'subnet name is: control'
  msg: 'subnet name is: storage'
  msg: 'subnet name is: data'
  msg: 'subnet name is: site'
  msg: 'subnet name is: local'
```

---

3. The next option is the conversion of the list to a dictionary

```yaml
  site_subnets_dict: "{{ site_subnets|combine }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  site_subnets_dict:
    control:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '1500'
      network: 100.99.97.0/24
    data:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '1500'
      network: 100.99.99.0/24
    local:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '1500'
      network: 100.99.44.1/22
    site:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '1500'
      network: 100.99.0.0/16
    storage:
      dhcp_from_ip: '30'
      dhcp_to_ip: '50'
      mtu: '9000'
      network: 100.99.98.0/24
```

Then, iterate the list created by *dict2items*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "subnet name is: {{ item.key }}"
      loop: "{{ site_subnets_dict|dict2items }}"
```

or, simply use filter *list* that extracts the dictionaries' keys

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "subnet name is: {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ site_subnets_dict|list }}"
```

Both options give (abridged) the same result

```yaml
  msg: 'subnet name is: control'
  msg: 'subnet name is: storage'
  msg: 'subnet name is: data'
  msg: 'subnet name is: site'
  msg: 'subnet name is: local'
```

This procedure will work if the keys of the dictionaries are unique, of course. To be sure, test it

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: site_subnets|length == site_subnets_dict|length
```

---